# Enterprise library 5.0 log to sql server not working

Tags: enterprise-library, sql-server-2008-express

I'm having problems with logging into sql server 2008 Express using Enterprise Library 5.0
It works in my development environment (VS2010) but NOT on my Server 2008/SQL Server 2008 Express.

To make sure it was not the database I also tested with a flat file. Did not work either.

Both files are present in my bin directory.

> Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.dll
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.dll

My web.config looks like this:

```
<configSections>
<section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
<sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
  <section name="Space4it.Registertime.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
<listeners>
  <add name="Database Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.FormattedDatabaseTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.Configuration.FormattedDatabaseTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    databaseInstanceName="TimeseddelLogging" writeLogStoredProcName="WriteLog"
    addCategoryStoredProcName="AddCategory" formatter="Text Formatter"
    traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp" />
</listeners>
<formatters>
  <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}"
    name="Text Formatter" />
</formatters>
<categorySources>
  <add switchValue="All" name="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Database Trace Listener" />
    </listeners>
  </add>
</categorySources>
<specialSources>
  <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Database Trace Listener" />
    </listeners>
  </allEvents>
  <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
  <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Database Trace Listener" />
    </listeners>
  </errors>
</specialSources>
</loggingConfiguration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="TimeseddelLogging" connectionString="Data Source=server\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=logging.database;User ID=username;pwd=password"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I connected manually (as a test) using this user and I'm able to enter data in the log table with this user.

I get this error:
Exception:

Message:

> Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type LogWriter, key ""

Stack:

> at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key) at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstanceTService at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.get_Writer() at Space4it.Common.Log.Log.DoLog(String message, String category, Dictionary`2 metaData, Exception ex, TraceEventType type, LogPriority priority, Int32 eventId) at Space4it.Registertime.Pages.TestForm.ButtonTest_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Inner Exception:
Message:

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter", name = "(none)". Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type Database cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value. ----------------------------------------------- At the time of the exception, the container was: Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterImpl,LogWriter.**default** (mapped from Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter, (none)) Resolving parameter "structureHolder" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterImpl(Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder structureHolder, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Instrumentation.ILoggingInstrumentationProvider instrumentationProvider, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.ILoggingUpdateCoordinator updateCoordinator) Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder,LogWriterStructureHolder.**default** (mapped from Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder, (none)) Resolving parameter "traceSources" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterStructureHolder(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.ILogFilter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] filters, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] traceSourceNames, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]] traceSources, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource allEventsTraceSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource notProcessedTraceSource, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource errorsTraceSource, System.String defaultCategory, System.Boolean tracingEnabled, System.Boolean logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch, System.Boolean revertImpersonation) Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource,General Resolving parameter "traceListeners" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource(System.String name, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Diagnostics.TraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] traceListeners, System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels level, System.Boolean autoFlush, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Instrumentation.ILoggingInstrumentationProvider instrumentationProvider) Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.ReconfigurableTraceListenerWrapper,Database Trace Listener (mapped from System.Diagnostics.TraceListener, Database Trace Listener) Resolving parameter "wrappedTraceListener" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.ReconfigurableTraceListenerWrapper(System.Diagnostics.TraceListener wrappedTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.ILoggingUpdateCoordinator coordinator) Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.FormattedDatabaseTraceListener,Database Trace Listener‌implementation (mapped from System.Diagnostics.TraceListener, Database Trace Listener‌implementation) Resolving parameter "database" of constructor Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Database.FormattedDatabaseTraceListener(Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database database, System.String writeLogStoredProcName, System.String addCategoryStoredProcName, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.ILogFormatter formatter) Resolving Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database,TimeseddelLogging

Inner exception Stack:

> at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocatorImplBase.GetInstance(Type serviceType, String key)

Hope someone can help me :-)

Have a nice day!

Comment: Having very similar issues. Did you find a resolution outside of StackOverflow?

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is indicating that Entlib hasn't initialized itself properly. The database is a red herring - you haven't gotten the logging block working at all right now.

Is the logging section defined in the <configSections> element of your web.config file?

Update:

You added your configSections element, but what you posted is malformed: <configSections></sectionGroup>. If that's accurate, then that's the problem, malformed config. Fix the close tag and it should start working.

Comment: Hi Chris.
Thanks for the reply.
I added a little more in my description but I think it is ok. It works in my development environment.
Could it be a X86/64 problem?
I compiled as AnyCPU but I can't figure out if Entlib has a problem when it runs on the 2008 Server which is an X64 system.
I did try compiling as X64, but with no lock.

Comment: The entlib team all use 64-bit machines for dev, so no, it's not a 32 vs 64 bit issue.

Comment: The config error was a paste-error. 
It should look ok now.
The rest of the application works. I only have problems with the logging.
Could it be that I need more the the 2 Logging.dll files?

Comment: Yes, you need Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll, and Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll as well in your bin directory or entlib as a whole won't work.